# Why changing "const" value in Angular 2 does not give error?

Tags: typescript, angular

The code is simple:

```
const num = 1;
num = 2;
console.log('num', num);
```

In [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/ofhs7jw3/), the browser console will show the following error, which is great:

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

However, the same codes in Angular 2 does not give any error, and at the end `num` equals **2**. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yRAgiV0rPZTsJhe5YYbF?p=preview).

Why changing "const" value in Angular 2 does not give error? Is this a bug? Thanks

Comment: Are you using babel to transpile?

Comment: @aray12 I am not sure.. I learned online ES6 can be compiled to ES5 using Babel or Traceur, while TypeScript has its own compiler. Maybe it is a TypeScript compiler bug?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I found out if I change from JavaScript to TypeScript in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/f44ncoe4/) it also equals 2, so maybe TypeScript compiler bug(?)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the typescript tag on this post. My guess is that typescript's compiler is compiling all `const` and `let` to `var` in order to support older browsers. It seems like this should fail at compile time

Comment: The docs https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/const.html#left-hand-side-of-assignment-cannot-be-a-constant say this should fail. What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @aray12 I don't know the TypeScript version, but Angular 2 is beta 12

Comment: This appears to be a bug with jsfiddle. I just ran through the example locally on my computer and got a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Online TypeScript compiler default target is lower than 'es6', so in generated code `const` is replaced by `var` for compatibility, but if you change config.js it to:

```
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    target: 'es6'
  }
```

compiler will output `const` and you'll see error.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to add this line `target: 'es6'` in **config.js**, but then I got error `Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: weird, I just add one line `target: 'es6'`, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vl2Yicarpxw5XiKf0iff?p=preview). Did you add some other things? thanks

Comment: Oh, you removed all content in `main.ts`, then it is not Angular 2 app any more...

Comment: `const` is purely ts/js language feature it has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: but if you don't remove content in **main.ts**, you will get error `Unexpected identifier`, I still want my Angular 2 app runs..

Comment: @kemsky whether it compiles to `var` or `const` shouldn't matter because you should be getting a compile error according to https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/const.html#left-hand-side-of-assignment-cannot-be-a-constant

Comment: @Hongbo Miao , it is entirely different question, you have to include es6 compatible angular version.